# Как сохранить объект который наследует HashMap<K,V> в Room DB

Tags: android, kotlin

Есть вот такой объект:

```
@Entity
class CCExchanges : HashMap<String, CCTradePairs>() {


    @PrimaryKey
    var id: Int = 0


    fun getExchangeList(): ArrayList<String> {
        return ArrayList(keys)
    }

    fun getTradePairs(exchange: String): CCTradePairs {
        return get(exchange) ?: CCTradePairs()
    }

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "CCExchanges(id=$id) ${super.toString()}"
    }
}
```

и вот такой метод для сохранения:

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun insert(ccExchanges: CCExchanges)
```

При сохранении никаких ошибок мне не выдает, но когда я пытаюсь этот объект достать из БД, то он полностью пустой.

Я подозреваю что это из-за наследования, но не могу понять как это правильно сделать?

Comment: Можно использовать композицию вместо наследования и написать TypeConverter для HashMap. Возможно есть и вариант получше.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, я так уже делаю, вариант рабочий, но не такой удобный.